# Typescript doesn't detect the right key type when looping through an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

This is **the code**:

```
const LarenComp: React.FC<{ entry: string }> = ({ entry }) => (
    <span>
        {entry}
    </span>
)

const PiComp: React.FC<{ entry: number }> = ({ entry }) => (
    <span>
        {entry}
    </span>
)

interface IMap {
  Lauren: {
    entry: string;
    comp: typeof LarenComp;
  };
  Pi: {
    entry: number;
    comp: typeof PiComp;
  };
}

const Map: IMap = {
  Lauren: {
    entry: "Laren",
    comp: LarenComp,
  },
  Pi: {
    entry: 3.14,
    comp: PiComp,
  },
};

let el: keyof IMap;
for (el in Map) {
  const elData = Map[el];

  let elements: React.ReactNode[] = [];

  elements = [
    ...elements,
    <elData.comp
      entry={elData.entry} // The error : Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'
    />,
  ];
}
```

**The error I get**: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.

**What I'm expecting** is that TS detects that assigned 'elData.entry' matchs the 'elData.comp' expected entry type.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this type of type safety like this as the type depends on the value of `el` on run-time and typescript cannot figure it out ahead.

Now why it goes to set `never` as the type of `entry` I have no idea!

If you have only a limited number of types, maybe you can use one of the type-guards here
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score -1):

If you want to loop through an array of components, you have to use a common type in your interface

```
type Comp = React.FC<{ entry: number | string }>;

interface IMap {
  Lauren: {
    entry: string;
    comp: Comp;
  };
  Pi: {
    entry: number;
    comp: Comp;
  };
}
```

That is because during the iteration, TypeScript has no idea if the prop `entry` of the current component take a `string` or a `number`, and cannot allow to pass a value of either one of those types in a prop that takes only one specific type among them.